# "Font has not been set" error when printing invoices

Tags: magento-2.1, invoice, zend-framework, fonts

Trying to print invoices.

I get the error "Font has not been set" and it refuses to generate PDFs.

[image: Error as shown in Sales]

This error seems to be linked to certain orders, though there is no rhyme or reason.  The next order could have the same items in the cart, but not have the error.

Is there a way to set the font or correct this error?

PS Magento newb so please be gentle.

Comment: A similar error occurred for me, but in an error report. Not the best solution, but I put the mentioned line of code inside a try-catch statement and the problem went away with no visible difference in the generated PDF.